# C# Linq - handle outer join and cartesian product

Tags: c#, sql, linq, join, datatable

Hi Stack Overflow community, I have a stored procedure (that I can't modify, so can only deal with the returned data) that can return data like this:

```
Group   Code Value
===========================
GroupA  13   123
GroupA  17   456
GroupB  17   789
```

However, I need to manipulate this result data to look like this:

```
Group   Code Value
===========================
GroupA  13   123
GroupA  17   456
GroupB  17   789
GroupB  13   NULL
```

... so that i can ultimately use LINQ's groupBy() on the **Code** column to get this result:

```
Group   Code Value
===========================
GroupA  17   456
GroupB  17   789

Group   Code Value
===========================
GroupA  13   123
GroupB  13   NULL
```

So we're pretty much doing a Cartesian product with the unique values in the **Group** column and the **Code** column, and joining this data to our original data. I can do this fairly simply in SQL like this:

```
DECLARE @TableData table (   
    [GroupName] nvarchar(200),
    Code int,
    Value int
); 

DECLARE @CartesianProductTable table
( 
    GroupName nvarchar(200),
    Code int
);

INSERT @TableData values 
('GroupA',  13,   123),
('GroupB',  17,   456),
('GroupA',  17,   789)

INSERT 
    @CartesianProductTable
SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT(GroupName) FROM @TableData
    ) T1, (
        SELECT DISTINCT(Code) FROM @TableData
    ) T2

SELECT 
    c.GroupName, 
    c.Code, 
    t.Value
FROM 
    @TableData t RIGHT OUTER join 
    @CartesianProductTable c on t.GroupName = c.GroupName AND t.Code = c.Code
```

So my question is, how do i do this in Linq after ive retrived the data as a DataTable in C#? I thought i could group by the **Code** column like this:

```
var tableDataGrouped = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(r => r.Field<int>("Code"))
                .Select(x => x.CopyToDataTable());
```

But it gives me data like this:

```
Group   Code Value
===========================
GroupA  17   456
GroupB  17   789

Group   Code Value
===========================
GroupA  13   123
```

When i need the returned LINQ data to be like this:

```
Group   Code Value
===========================
GroupA  17   456
GroupB  17   789

Group   Code Value
===========================
GroupA  13   123
GroupB  13   NULL
```

I'm fairly new to LINQ so any tips you could point out would help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a trick question because the solution is what you initially expect

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Group", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Code", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns["Value"].AllowDBNull = true;

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "GroupA", 13,123});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "GroupA", 17,456});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "GroupB", 17,789});

            List<int> codes = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<int>("Code")).Distinct().ToList();
            var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Group")).ToList();

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                foreach (int code in codes)
                {
                    if (!group.Any(x => x.Field<int>("Code") == code))
                    {
                        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { group.Key, code, DBNull.Value });
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that gave me the output i needed! Much appreciated :)